# WCF NullReferenceException in the Finalizer

Tags: windows, wcf, unhandled-exception, finalizer

We had problems with WCF that took us a long time to diagnose so I'm posting them here in case someone has similar issues (haven't found a reference anywhere else).

Our processes would often crash with the following unhandled exceptions:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OverlappedContext.CompleteCallback(UInt32 error, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
 at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
 at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at System.Threading.Overlapped.Free(NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlappedPtr)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OverlappedContext.Free()
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OverlappedContext.FreeOrDefer()
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Abort(TraceEventType traceEventType, String timeoutErrorString, TransferOperation transferOperation)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationPool`2.EndpointConnectionPool.CloseIdleConnection(TItem connection, TimeSpan timeout)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IdlingCommunicationPool`2.IdleTimeoutEndpointConnectionPool.IdleTimeoutIdleConnectionPool.OnIdle()
 at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
 at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
 at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at System.Threading.Overlapped.Free(NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlappedPtr)
 at System.Net.AsyncRequestContext.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
 at System.Net.RequestContextBase.Finalize()
```

Exceptions usually occured several hours after staring the process, sometimes after a few minutes.

Strangely they would only show up after installing the Jan. 2013 Windows Updates (and go away after uninstalling them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turned out to be `IClientChannel`.

We forgot to dispose the channel after use and called `Dispose()` from the finalizer thread.

My guess is that IClientChannel uses unmanaged resources that have to be released from the same thread that created them.

After calling `Dispose()` from the same thread the issue went away.